Quadratic polynomial matrix always singular?
I am fitting a quadratic to a surface in (x,y). The formula is the usual
$$f(x,y) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2y + a_3xy + a_4x^2 + a_5y^2$$
and the matrix used to fit the coefficients is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & x_{1} & y_{1} & x_{1} y_{1} & x_{1}^2 & y_{1}^2 \\
    1       & x_{2} & y_{2} & x_{2} y_{2} & x_{2}^2 & y_{2}^2 \\
    \vdots       & \vdots& \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    1       & x_{n} & y_{n} & x_{n} y_{n} & x_{n}^2 & y_{n}^2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
There is complete freedom to choose the locations (x,y) but whenever I construct the matrix its singular values drop to zero by position 4 or 5. This means there is only enough information to estimate 4 or 5 of the coefficients.
I can't quite understand where the linear dependence is. But anyway, I was wondering how best to choose (x,y) to give the most linearly independent matrix - hopefully of rank 6 so I can obtain the 6 coefficients reliably.

What are your x and y values?

Good point! They are chosen to lie on the circle... so x^2+y^2 = 1... which is the cause of the singular behavior. However, the question remains what is the best choice of (x,y). Is this something that Fisher Information can be applied to?

If you have a choice of x and y values (you're in control of the experimental conditions) then there is a huge literature on "design of experiments" that can help you to pick observations that will optimize the uncertainty in the fitted parameters.

The Fisher information matrix gives you information about the uncertainty in your fitted parameters, but generally, you'll come up with a scalar measure to optimize that is derived from the matrix.  e.g. the trace is sometimes minimized.

This is quite natural, you can't make a second order polynomial pass through an arbitrary number of points.
The same happens with single variable functions: If you are fitting data with a second order polynomial, you can only specify three points. Specifying more than three points leads to either impossible or undetermined linear systems.
